# How to read individual logs from linux server into another log file using perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I am new in perl, i have a question i.e 'How to read individual logs from linux server into another log file using perl script', I need to capture the individual logs from different paths and output the result of those log files and store to a file in another location.These Logs are generated in Linux Server..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to merge a set of files into one? Why do you think you need perl for this?

Comment: No i have individual path log files are there its running the Linux server,but i need capture that logs into another location of individual files.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Copy the files? Just check the most recent lines? I think you need to be a bit more explicit about your needs here.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily cat them all together, if that's what you want:

```
cat log1 log2 log3 > result
```

**Update:**

If you want recent lines from the logs in different output files, use tail:

```
tail -50 /opt/psauto1/tester.log > /some/other/file
tail -50 /opt/psauto1/testdata.log  > /some/other/file2
tail -50 /opt/view/test/itresult.log  > /some/other/file3
tail -50 /opt/test/glr.log > /some/other/file4
tail -50 /opt/test/glr/glrdata.log > /some/other/file5
tail -50 /opt/test/glr/result.log > /some/other/file6 
tail -50 /opttest/glr/output.log > /some/other/file7
```

You can even put this in a loop and run it every 5 seconds:

```
while [ true ]
do
  tail -50 /opt/psauto1/tester.log > /some/other/file
  tail -50 /opt/psauto1/testdata.log  > /some/other/file2
  tail -50 /opt/view/test/itresult.log  > /some/other/file3
  tail -50 /opt/test/glr.log > /some/other/file4
  tail -50 /opt/test/glr/glrdata.log > /some/other/file5
  tail -50 /opt/test/glr/result.log > /some/other/file6 
  tail -50 /opttest/glr/output.log > /some/other/file7 
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: i need recent logs capture from server.am using tail -f input path file > output path file , but multiple logs not captured at a time.

Comment: i have the 7 logs I/P logs eg: 1)/opt/psauto1/tester.log , 2)/opt/psauto1/testdata.log, 3) /opt/view/test/itresult.log, 4)/opt/test/glr.log, 5)/opt/test/glr/glrdata.log, 6)/opt/test/glr/result.log, 7)/opttest/glr/output.log. so, i want capture  recent those logs into another location individual path...

Comment: thanks dogbane, i trying the code but not done, i want output files stored in individual paths..

Answer (score 0):

As for `tail -f`, you can do it like this:

```
(
    tail -f file1 &
    tail -f file2 & 
)>>total_file
```

The `()` will group commands together (`fork`ing a subshell), and `>>`will append to a file, and `&` will force commands to background.

As for perl, `select` in [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm#select) manual pretty much explains how to do it.